# While using Ajax to POST record, I receive the message: ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: player_bonuse)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, csrf

I have read all posts concerning csrf authentication and posting records using ajax and have made changes.   Although the "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" issue has gone away, I still suspect this might possibly still be the problem.  I am using Rails 5.1. I have worked a long time on this issue and would appreciate help, please.

This part of the application has a single HTML form with a wheel which is spun using jquery.  The form receives hidden data from the controller which the jquery script accesses from the form. The resulting position of the spin provides the rest of the data to be written to the PlayerBonuses table.   The problem occurs when the program attempts to post this result to the table.

Included at the bottom is the data returned and error message in three tests.  The data does not have any missing columns, that I can see.

1. The Ajax script with -  data: player_bonuse and dataType: 'json'
2. The Ajax script with -  data: JSON.stringify({player_bonuse})
3. For comparison's sake, the data returned through a normal entry of bonus data through the Rails restful method.

Note:

a) Number 1 resembles more closely the restful result

b) Number 2 includes the parameter name, "player_bonuse" (as does the restful result)

c) Number 2 allocates the result => nil which is not apparent in 1.

d) Neither show the CSRF data in the header which exists in 3, although the authenticity error no longer is displayed.

Thanking you in advance for any help/insights you can provide.

The player_bonuse model:

```
 class PlayerBonuse < ApplicationRecord

   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :bonus_table_reference
   belongs_to :bonus_reference
   belongs_to :award_reference

   validates :user_id, presence: true
   validates :bonus_table_reference_id, presence: true
   validates :bonus_reference_id, presence: true
   validates :award_reference_id, presence: true
   validates :date_awarded, presence: true
   validates :award_amount, presence: true

 end
```

The Controller spin method:

```
 def return_daily_spin
     @player_bonuse = PlayerBonuse.new
     @user = User.find(current_user.id)
     @date_awarded = Time.zone.now
 end
```

The Controller Create method:

```
 def create
   @player_bonuse = PlayerBonuse.new(player_bonuse_params)
   if @player_bonuse.save
      if @player_bonuse.bonus_reference_id = 2
          redirect_to lobby_path(:user_id => current_user.id)
      else
         respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to @player_bonuse, notice: 'Player bonus was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @player_bonuse }
            end
       end
     else
       respond_to do |format|
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @player_bonuse.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
     end
 end
```

The Controller Table Parameters:

```
 def player_bonuse_params
  params.require(:player_bonuse).permit(:id, :user_id, :bonus_table_reference_id, :bonus_reference_id, :award_reference_id, :date_awarded, :award_amount, :search)
 end
```

The AJAX Post Method:

```
         $.ajax({
           url:  '/player_bonuse',
           type: 'POST',
           beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
           data: player_bonuse,
          dataType: 'json'
         }).done(function (data) {
         if (data.Success) {
          alert('success!');
         } else {
             alert('failure');
         }           
        });
```

The result processing with the above code:

Processing by PlayerBonusesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user_id"=>"1", "bonus_table_reference_id"=>"10", "bonus_reference_id"=>"2", "award_reference_id"=>"1", "date_awarded"=>"2018-12-19 09:38:06 +1000", "award_amount"=>"5000"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: player_bonuse

---

The result using the code "data: JSON.stringify({player_bonuse})"

Processing by PlayerBonusesController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"{\"player_bonuse\":{\"user_id\":\"1\",\"bonus_table_reference_id\":11,\"bonus_reference_id\":2,\"award_reference_id\":1,\"date_awarded\":\"2018-12-19 11:02:41  1000\",\"award_amount\":10000}}"=>nil}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: player_bonuse):________________________________________________________________________________

The result if adding the a bonus through Rails Restful Process:

The"authenticity_token"=>"nkcECEzAYJQvDQ26/Ij5eslDOzk8umY/c0aexJGCVsWR1F6CYl+7SH4FgcJhaBS656CRf5rl0Ipa3W0tVksCRA==", "player_bonuse"=>{"user_id"=>"1", "bonus_table_reference_id"=>"11", "bonus_reference_id"=>"2", "award_reference_id"=>"1", "date_awarded(3i)"=>"18", "date_awarded(2i)"=>"12", "date_awarded(1i)"=>"2018", "award_amount"=>"10000"}, "commit"=>"Create"}

---

Comment: did you try putting `player_bonuse` in `params` object? Like: `params: { player_bonuse: ... }...`

Comment: Thank you Thanh.   I have only seen this post since resolving the problem, but I do appreciate your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not have solved this without Bhargav Reddy's help.   Thank you Bhargav.

Previous allocation of data was:

```
      var player_bonuse = {
            user_id: player_id,
            bonus_table_reference_id: bonus_table_id,
            bonus_reference_id: bonus_ref,
            award_reference_id: award_ref,
            date_awarded:  award_date,
            award_amount:  bonus
       };
```

I have now changed my code to be:

```
         var player_bonuse

         $.ajax({
            url:  '/player_bonuse',
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
            data: {player_bonuse: {
            bonus_table_reference_id: bonus_table_id,
            bonus_reference_id: bonus_ref,
            award_reference_id: award_ref,
            date_awarded: award_date,
            award_amount: bonus
           }},
           dataType: 'json'
           }).done(function (data) {
           if (data.Success) {
             alert('success!');
           } else {
             alert('failure');
           }           
          });
```

My controller has no changes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know but once try like this

```
def create
params.permit( :user_id, :bonus_table_reference_id, :bonus_reference_id, :award_reference_id, :date_awarded, :award_amount )
 @player_bonuse = PlayerBonuse.new (:user_id =>params[:user_id], :bonus_table_reference_id => params[:bonus_table_reference_id],:bonus_reference_id => params[:bonus_reference_id],:award_reference_id => params[:award_reference_id], :date_awarded => params[:date_awarded],:award_amount => params[:award_amount])

  if @player_bonuse.save
   if @player_bonuse.bonus_reference_id = 2
      redirect_to lobby_path(:user_id => current_user.id)
   else
     respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @player_bonuse, notice: 'Player bonus was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @player_bonuse }
        end
   end
 else
   respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @player_bonuse.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
end
```

Convert params to string if needed and give database column symbols in new statement

Comment: Hi Bhargav,   thanks for the help.  I get the following error message doing this:

Comment: Sorry - pressed enter before finishing.   "ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 8, expected 0..1)):"   Since only 6 arguments are showing, I am assuming the other two are the csrf credentials?

Comment: Whoops - it appears it is only commenting on the number of columns in the permit statement - where there are 8.   I do not send :id or :search since :id is created upon save and :search is used in an :index form.  This does not matter, does it?

Comment: Then don't send those two param values into permit and new statement as well

Comment: I took those fields out and now get; Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15349ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 6, expected 0..1)):    The 500 error was on the previous error as well.

Comment: sorry my mistake, i edited my answer once check it out

Comment: That works.   Many thanks!  But is this solution telling me that I should have done something differently at the Ajax code that would have fixed this?   I would never ever have thought of doing it this way - ever!

Comment: I don't know but what I think is, In your code   player_bonuse_params is just permitting the required data  but it is'nt returning any object ,so you are getting nil param_bonuse .That's what i know tq.